# AS3 car race game?

Tags: actionscript-3, action

I am trying to make a racing game with an overhead view looking down. There will be a separate mc for the ground and another separate mc for the players car. How can I do this? O ya and just in case i am thinking the way I did:
     I tried to "rotate" the ground but when the car moves down the ground it moves away from the registration point, so therefore it rotates non relative to the car i want to make this game in as3.

Answer (score 2):

Put the car on top of a separate holder movieclip, and put the graphics for the ground *inside* the ground holder. As the car moves and rotates, apply rotations to the holder MC, but apply movement to the ground inside the holder. This way, rotations will always take place relative to the registration point of the holder, but the ground graphics can still move relative to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for. In the meantime, you can look at the [online Risk Game](http://www.hasbro.com/risk/flash_world.cfm) I helped built.  Once in the site, click Super Commuter. If this game is similar to what you are trying to build, you can ask questions relating to what you observe there.